# Setting date for date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

In my appliaction i am fetching data from database,in that i am fetching date also.So if user clicks any particulat item means i will fetch that startdate also and i have to set it  as default date in dat picker in the screen.Now the fetching data is coming as correct and 1 dialog is appearing with the fetched data with 2 options "SET"  and "CANCEL" if i click set means that fetched date is not coming as default date only the current date is coming  as default date.Help me ..Thanks in advance.

My coding :

```
 c = Calendar.getInstance();               
               SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
               System.out.println("After format");
               Date pickdefdate=null;
               String pickdefdatepar=null;
               try {
                   System.out.println("Inside try="+date);
              pickdefdate=sdf.parse(date);
              System.out.println("dddddddd="+pickdefdate);

              c.setTime(pickdefdate);
              System.out.println("After parse");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               System.out.println("B4 setting");

               mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
               mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);           
               showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);


protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
     {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                System.out.println("in dia="+mDay);
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            }
            return null;
        }


     private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        System.out.println("Inside dia");
                        mYear = year;
                        mMonth = monthOfYear;
                        mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend onPrepareDialog function

```
 @Override
```

`protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {`
`switch (id) {`
`case date_picker_dialog_show:`
`((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);`
`break;`
`}}`

this will update the date picker date when it show

Comment: Thanks Jaisoni..I put your code after oncreate(),But still the current date is coming..Whether i have to do some other modifications..

Comment: @prakash.k are you sure that your mYear, mMonth, mDay variable are updated when you call showDialog() function. And one question do you want to update date every time when you call showDialog() or just once when dialog first time created.